# Lua and IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, lua, intellij-13, intellij-14

Do someone know a good plugin to program Lua using IntelliJ? I'm using the one from [sylvanaar](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/5055?pr=idea) but it is painfully slow.

UPDATE: slowness due to code styling.

UPDATE 2: I gave up on using LUA on IntelliJ I found that https://studio.zerobrane.com/ is a better fits what I need and it is very fast.

Comment: The one from Sylvanaar doesn't work with latest versions anymore, so we're left without Lua support.

Comment: @Danita give ZeroBrane a try: I liked it when I used to work on LUA. But cannot say how it is nowadays...

Comment: I'm sure it's great but I work on mixed language projects and I'd prefer not to switch IDEs every time I need to work on a different file :-)

Comment: Yeah, that wouldn't be ideal, would it? GEdit forever!!! :D

Answer (score 7):

There is also the EmmyLua plugin, which appears relatively stable and receives regular updates:

- [Website](https://emmylua.github.io/)
- [GitHub](https://github.com/EmmyLua/IntelliJ-EmmyLua)
- [JetBrains Plugins Repository](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9768-emmylua)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are any alternatives for this plugin.

Maybe that's the reason why my IDEA is hanging for like 8 seconds when appending a new line...

Comment: it is. disable that "plugin" and it will run as fast as a bullet train but IDEA would as useful as gedit or notepad.